# R formula in survfit

Tags: r, formula, survival-analysis

I am having trouble with formulas, environments, and `survfit()`.

Things work fine for `lm()` but they fail for `survfit()`.

## General problem statement:

I am fitting a series of formulas to some data.  So, I call the
modeling function with the formula passed as a variable.  Later,
I want to work with the formula from the fitted object.

(From my naive point of view, the trouble comes from survfit not
recording the environment.)

## Detailed Example

Expected behaviour as seen in `lm()`:

```
library("plyr")

preds <- c("wt", "qsec")

f <- function() {
  lm(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars)
}

fits <- alply(preds, 1, function(pred)
{
  modform <- reformulate(pred, response = "mpg")

  lm(modform, data = mtcars)
})

fits[[1]]$call$formula
##modform
formula(fits[[1]])
## mpg ~ wt
## <environment: 0x1419d1a0>
```

Even though `fits[[1]]$call$formula` resolves to `modform` I can
still get the original formula with `formula(fits[[1]])`.

But things fail for `survfit()`:

```
library("plyr")
library("survival")

preds <- c("resid.ds", "rx", "ecog.ps")

fits <- 
  alply(preds, 1, function(pred)
  {
    modform <- paste("Surv(futime, fustat)", pred, sep = " ~ ")
    modform <- as.formula(modform)
    print(modform)

    fit <- survfit(modform, data = ovarian)
  })

fits[[1]]$call$formula
## modform
formula(fits[[1]])
## Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'modform' not found
```

Here (and in contrast to lm-fits), `formula(fits[[1]])` does not
work!

So, my specific question is: How can I get back the formula used
to fit `fits[[1]]`?

Comment: `fit <- eval(substitute(survfit(modform, data = ovarian), list(modform = modform)))` or simply add the formula back into the survfit object `fit$call$formula <- modform` then return `fit`

Comment: Thanks!  That works.  I take it there is no way recovering the formula from `fits[[1]]` as it is produced in the example code of the question? In that case: if you write your comment as an answer, I'll accept that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that when `x$formula` is `NULL`, for an `lm` object there is a backup plan to get the formula; this doesn't exist for `survfit` objects

```
library("plyr")
library("survival")

preds <- c("wt", "qsec")
f <- function() lm(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars)

fits <- alply(preds, 1, function(pred) {
  modform <- reformulate(pred, response = "mpg")
  lm(modform, data = mtcars)
})

fits[[1]]$formula
# NULL
```

The formula can be extracted with `formula(fits[[1]])` which uses the `formula` generic. The `lm` S3 method for `formula` is

```
stats:::formula.lm

# function (x, ...) 
# {
#   form <- x$formula
#   if (!is.null(form)) {
#     form <- formula(x$terms)
#     environment(form) <- environment(x$formula)
#     form
#   }
#   else formula(x$terms)
# }
```

So when `fits[[1]]$formula` returns `NULL`, `forumla.lm` looks for a `terms` attribute in the object and finds the formula that way

```
fits[[1]]$terms
```

The `survfit` objects don't have `x$formula` or `x$terms`, so `formula(x)` givens an error

```
preds <- c("resid.ds", "rx", "ecog.ps")
fits <-  alply(preds, 1, function(pred) {
    modform <- paste("Surv(futime, fustat)", pred, sep = " ~ ")
    modform <- as.formula(modform)
    fit <- survfit(modform, data = ovarian)
  })

fits[[1]]$formula
# NULL

formula(fits[[1]]) ## error

formula(fits[[1]]$terms)
# list()
```

You can fix this by inserting the formula into the call and evaluating it

```
modform <- as.formula(paste("Surv(futime, fustat)", 'rx', sep = " ~ "))
substitute(survfit(modform, data = ovarian), list(modform = modform))
# survfit(Surv(futime, fustat) ~ rx, data = ovarian)

eval(substitute(survfit(modform, data = ovarian), list(modform = modform)))

# Surv(futime, fustat) ~ rx

# Call: survfit(formula = Surv(futime, fustat) ~ rx, data = ovarian)
# 
#      n events median 0.95LCL 0.95UCL
# rx=1 13      7    638     268      NA
# rx=2 13      5     NA     475      NA
```

Or by manually putting the formula into `x$call$formula`

```
fit <- survfit(modform, data = ovarian)
fit$call$formula
# modform
fit$call$formula <- modform
fit$call$formula
# Surv(futime, fustat) ~ rx

fit
# Call: survfit(formula = Surv(futime, fustat) ~ rx, data = ovarian)
# 
#      n events median 0.95LCL 0.95UCL
# rx=1 13      7    638     268      NA
# rx=2 13      5     NA     475      NA
```

Comment: Really nice answer.  Much appreciated.